# How to query paragraphs content?

Tags: 7, paragraphs

Does any one have an example how I can query the paragraph entity type of a given node ?

Let's say I have a node that contains a field 'field_paragraph' that is linked to the paragraph module . How do I query all that data ?

Thanks,
Yaron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to *query* (output? render?) paragraph field values.
If the idea is to print the value in a template, you may find some clues in this page: https://www.drupal.org/node/2532824

```
<?php print render($content['field_paragraph']); ?>
```

But that will also depend on the theme you are using and how do you use it